# How do I improve the clarity of my voice?

Tags: voice, voice-training

I am totally unhappy with my voice. In my opinion, my voice sounds like Kermit the Frog. I have practiced using a stick between my teeth, but this only helps with articulation.

Is it possible to train my voice to improve its tone and clarity?

Comment: Have you looked into [modifying your diet to affect](http://voicestudio.kristinaseleshanko.com/ThingsThatAffectYourVoice.htm) your voice?

Comment: A lot can be done to change the quality of your voice, both in good and bad ways, but it's nigh impossible for people who can't see and hear you sing in real time to help you with that, and it takes a lot of knowledge and experience to know what to look and listen for and what to change to make things better. Basically, your best option is to hire a teacher. Anything else is a shot in the dark and you might make your voice worse.

Answer (score 1):

Go get some classes on singing... Talent is really a small part of it, and most of the rest you can learn. It can be harder or easier, but you can probably have a richer sound if you study with someone who knows what they're doing.

If you can't afford a teacher, there are tons of videos on the internet about breath support and intonation, that can help you a long way, but I strongly recommend you find help, as you can damage your voice if you do something wrong...